# Any Shortcut to add +1/2/3/4 weeks in current date in KendoUI Datepciker?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

I am working on a scenario where I have a KendoUI date picker.
 is it possible to have a quick selectable option for + 1/2/3/4 weeks,

**Suppose, I have selected 1 May in datePicker, then if I press "1".. then it should add 7 days(1 week) in current date.
if I press "2", then it should add 14 days (2 weeks) in current date
using Kendo UI.**

is there any solution for this?

Comment: Do you mean when the calendar pop up is raised ?

Comment: @ Richard  - Yes

Answer (score 0):

The DatePicker has built-in keyboard shortcuts:
https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/keyboard-navigation

> - Focus:
>
>   - Access key + w focuses the widget
> - Closed popup:
>
>   - enter triggers change event
>   - esc closes the popup
>   - alt down arrow opens the popup
>   - alt up arrow closes the popup
> - Opened popup (date view):
>
>   - left arrow highlights previous day
>   - right arrow highlights next day
>   - up arrow highlights same day from the previous week
>   - down arrow highlights same day from the next week
>   - ctrl left arrow navigates to previous month
>   - ctrl right arrow navigates to next month
>   - ctrl up arrow navigates to previous view
>   - ctrl down arrow navigates to next view
>   - home highlights first day of the month
>   - end highlights last day of the month
>   - enter if in "month" view selects the highlighted day. In other views navigates to a lower view

The normal DatePicker behavior is for keyboard input to sent to the input box.

Not sure the benefit of having such a specialized dialog feature (1 is +1 week, 2 is +2 week,...) that would prevent typing in an actual date.

There are no component options for specifying your own keyboard handling so trying to override any keyboard handlers that the component is using would be tricky and fragile.